# TripleDES Decryption Issues

Tags: php, vb.net, encryption, cryptography, 3des

I have decoded The string "Test" with 3des using the following functions in Visual Basic:

```
Imports System.IO
Imports System.Text
Imports System.Security.Cryptography

Friend Class cTripleDES

    ' define the triple des provider
    Private m_des As New TripleDESCryptoServiceProvider

    ' define the string handler
    Private m_utf8 As New ASCIIEncoding

    ' define the local property arrays
    Private m_key() As Byte
    Private m_iv() As Byte

    Public Sub New(ByVal key() As Byte, ByVal iv() As Byte)
        Me.m_key = key
        Me.m_iv = iv
    End Sub

    Public Function Encrypt(ByVal input() As Byte) As Byte()
        Return Transform(input, m_des.CreateEncryptor(m_key, m_iv))
    End Function

    Public Function Decrypt(ByVal input() As Byte) As Byte()
        Return Transform(input, m_des.CreateDecryptor(m_key, m_iv))
    End Function

    Public Function Encrypt(ByVal text As String) As String
        Dim input() As Byte = m_utf8.GetBytes(text)
        Dim output() As Byte = Transform(input, _
                        m_des.CreateEncryptor(m_key, m_iv))
        Return Convert.ToBase64String(output)
    End Function

    Public Function Decrypt(ByVal text As String) As String
        Dim input() As Byte = Convert.FromBase64String(text)
        Dim output() As Byte = Transform(input, _
                         m_des.CreateDecryptor(m_key, m_iv))
        Return m_utf8.GetString(output)
    End Function

    Private Function Transform(ByVal input() As Byte, _
        ByVal CryptoTransform As ICryptoTransform) As Byte()
        ' create the necessary streams
        Dim memStream As MemoryStream = New MemoryStream
        Dim cryptStream As CryptoStream = New  _
            CryptoStream(memStream, CryptoTransform, _
            CryptoStreamMode.Write)
        ' transform the bytes as requested
        cryptStream.Write(input, 0, input.Length)
        cryptStream.FlushFinalBlock()
        ' Read the memory stream and convert it back into byte array
        memStream.Position = 0
        Dim result(CType(memStream.Length - 1, System.Int32)) As Byte
        memStream.Read(result, 0, CType(result.Length, System.Int32))
        ' close and release the streams
        memStream.Close()
        cryptStream.Close()
        ' hand back the encrypted buffer
        Return result
    End Function
```

I Called it using this functions

```
Imports System.Security.Cryptography
Imports System.IO
Imports System.Text
Module tripledes

    Function Encrypt(ByVal text As String) As String
        ' define the local key and vector byte arrays
        Dim key() As Byte = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("MyKeygoeshere12345678901")
        Dim iv() As Byte = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("Heretheiv")

        ' instantiate the class with the arrays
        Dim des As New cTripleDES(key, iv)

        ' the value of decryptedData should be "test",
        ' but for our example purposes, let's re-encrypt it
        Return des.Encrypt(text)
    End Function
    Function Decrypt(ByVal text As String) As String
        ' define the local key and vector byte arrays
        Dim key() As Byte = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("MyKeygoeshere12345678901")
        Dim iv() As Byte = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("Heretheiv")

        ' instantiate the class with the arrays
        Dim des As New cTripleDES(key, iv)

        ' the value of decryptedData should be "test",
        ' but for our example purposes, let's re-encrypt it
        Return des.Decrypt(text)
    End Function
End Module
```

But if I try to decrypt it with the following PHP function, the output is agkk and not Test as my Input and as I excepted.

```
function decrypt($content){
$key = "MyKeygoeshere12345678901";
$iv = "Heretheiv";
return  mcrypt_cbc(MCRYPT_3DES, $key,  base64_decode($content), MCRYPT_DECRYPT, $iv);
}
```

Could somebody please tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

A couple things:

1. Use the MCRYPT_TripleDES cypher instead.
2. Generate a valid IV.

You should also include how you are generated the encrypted value.

Regardless, here is a working example you can use as you see fit.

```
<?php

$content = "your_secret_string";
$secret  = "your_secret_key";

$iv = mcrypt_create_iv(mcrypt_get_block_size(MCRYPT_TripleDES, MCRYPT_MODE_CBC), MCRYPT_DEV_RANDOM);

function encrypt($iv, $content, $secret)
{
    return base64_encode(mcrypt_cbc(MCRYPT_TripleDES, $secret, $content, MCRYPT_ENCRYPT, $iv));
}

function decrypt($iv, $content, $secret)
{
    return mcrypt_cbc(MCRYPT_TripleDES, $secret, base64_decode($content), MCRYPT_DECRYPT, $iv);
}

$encrypted = encrypt($iv, $content, $secret);

echo 'Encrypted: '. encrypt($iv, $content, $secret) . '<br>';;
echo 'Decrypted: '. decrypt($iv, $encrypted, $secret) . '<br>';
```

Comment: Keep in mind, this is deprecated as of 5.5. It is recommend to use mcrypt_generic() instead.

Comment: That isn't working either, now I get dynamic-shit like: ZÚêçv:Y or S« qx¢ 
The IV must be the same as in the VB Application, mustn't it?

Comment: Yes, the IV must be the same between the two. I'm not sure why you would be getting different results. How are you retrieving and assembling the bytes generated from your VB to PHP script?

Comment: As you can read in the source code, I Base64 encode it, transmit it and then decode it. The IV in the VB Application I've set to "Heretheiv". Your PHP Script generates an new IV on every run, so I get an other result each time the script runs.

Comment: My script is just an example. If your VB script generates your IV, then pass the IV + encrypted content to the PHP script to use.

Comment: The IV isn't been generated, its static set to "Heretheiv"

Comment: They probably aren't the same. They are being applied differently. Your VB is converted UTF8 data into bytes. Your PHP script is using strings with whatever your default encoding is.

Comment: Can you please tell me how to make the PHP script convert the string to an working format or encoding?

Comment: @Flole Note that the IV *must* be different every time the encryption function is called; otherwise certain aspects of security may be compromised.

Comment: @ntoskrnl If it's working, I will change it, but if not, all aspects of security are useless ;)